# Which numbers; 0 or 1 disable/enable gconftool?

Tags: command-line, compiz, execute-command

Will this command enable or disable unredirection?

```
gconftool-2 --set /apps/compizconfig-1/profiles/Default/plugins/composite/screen0/options/unredirect_fullscreen_windows --type bool 0
```

I think 0 is for disable and 1 for enable, but I just have to check... **:)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, `0` is the disabled state. It should be on (`1`) since Ubuntu 12.10. You can turn it off with the command in the answer if this causes problems for you.